# No route matches on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have installed one of my RoR app on my local computer from GitHub.

And trying to have it running on my local machine
But after successful login they throwing me this error which drives me crazy.

I tried to find out solutions, but failed.
Can u guys please explain me possible reasons for this error?

Thanks.

Comment: we need more info. show the full error and provide the link to github

Answer (score 0):

**No Route Matches** basically means you're trying to load a URL / Route which doesn't exist in your `config/routes.rb` file

To fix it, you have to look at the request you've sent to Rails & see if it's matched within the routes file. If not, [ActionDispatch::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) will not be able to direct your request to the correct controller / action

You need to give us the actual error & show the `routes.rb` file to get an accurate answer